# Will slock work on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, compatibility

Will the [slock](http://tools.suckless.org/slock) screen locking utility work on Mac OS X, or is it just for Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. os x uses a different windowing system.

Comment: Yup - for OS X, leverage a password-protected screen saver, or the screen locking feature of Apple Remote Desktop. Even if you don't own ARD, it could probably be hacked by an enterprising command-line user.

Comment: I'll second a passworded screensaver. Just set one of your screen corners to activate the screensaver, and then you have on-demand locking.

Comment: I know. But I prefer the added security of slock seeing as how there is no indication that you have to enter a password.

Comment: What's the added security? People who know your password probably also know about that fancy screen locking utility you're using.

Comment: But people that don't know my password won't know that there is something running to enter the password into so they can't brute-force hack into it.